# Undertow server networking over wifi

Tags: networking, server, wildfly-8, undertow

I have two to three systems, let say System A,B,C which are connected to a wireless hotspot on any of the three system

On system A, I have undertow server running, in which I can access on the very system A over "localhost:8080" in the browser or apps. I want System B,C to also be able to access the service using a particular IP address not necessarily "localhost:8080". I mean I want internet browser or apps on system B and C to be able to access the same services render by by undertow server on System A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it solved by listening on the very ip address of the wireless device. I mean instead of listening on localhost:8080 o 127.0.0.1:8080, I rather listen on the ip address of the device that serves the wireless hotspot that other devices are connected to. For example if system B serves the wireless and it's ip address is 192.168.43.128 then undertow server should listen on 192.168.43.128:8080 `.addHttpListener(8080, "192.168.43.128")` . Then system A,B,C connected to the wireless serve by system B will have access to the resource serve by undertow server using 192.168.43.128:8080